# invariant subspaces of a matrix over complex

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Take $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ then I am asked to find the invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{C^2}$ under $A$. Obviously $\mathbb{C^2}$ is one of them trivially. However, I was thinking can $\mathbb{R^2}$ be also an invariant subspace of $A$?

Comment: Yes, you're right that $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{C}^2$ which is invariant under $A$. This is because $A$ has all real entries. Another one is $i\Bbb{R}^2$ (the set of $2$-tuples whose entries are purely imaginary)

Comment: If $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ then the invariant subspaces of $\Bbb C^n$ are of the form $U+iV$ where $U$ and $V$ are invariant subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: $\Bbb R^2$ is certainly invariant, the question is whether it's a subspace. It seems to me that in this context "subspace"  typically refers to a _complex_ subspace of $\Bbb C^2$, in which case $\Bbb R^2$ is _not_ ann invariant subspace, since it's not a subspace at all. (If this is a homework question you should ask the authorities whether "subspace" means "complex subspace"...)